Unable to solve the captcha correctly using pytesseract
I have created a python code to read the captcha using OCR and fill the form further. I have used pytesseract library for the recognition of characters in the captcha. I am unable to retrieve the correct sequence of characters after reading it.
This is the code-
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageOps
import pytesseract

# Open the image file
image_path = "image.png"
image = Image.open(image_path)

# Preprocess the image
# Convert to grayscale
image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)

# Apply a median filter to remove noise
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter(size=3))

# Apply thresholding to get a binary image
threshold = 128
image = image.point(lambda p: p > threshold and 255)

# Perform OCR
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--psm 8')

print("Recognized text:", text)

This is the example of captcha for which I want to create the code and read it.

Please suggest me an alternative or more effective method through which I can read them successfully.

You should provide more information about why your code is not retrieving the image's text. Is there any error?

No no, the code is retrieving the image text but it is  not correctly reading it. What technique should I so that the correct characters are retrieved from the image.

tesseract cannot correctly identify the text capthca in most images. It is best to use a third-party api.

fyi: https://sourceforge.net/software/compare/2Captcha-vs-CapSolver-vs-NextCaptcha/
